# What is the difference? "we live" vs "we are living"

Tags: present-tense, present-continuous

What is the difference between these sentences?

> If this theory about parallel universes is correct, it means that
>   **we are living** in more than one universe at the same time.
>
> If this theory about parallel universes is correct, it means that
>   **we live** in more than one universe at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you use present continuous **we are ...ing** to describe an ongoing situation. For a small number of verbs called [stative verbs](http://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/verbs/stative-verbs/), we can use present simple to describe an ongoing situation that will continue for the foreseeable future.

**think** is a stative verb, so if there were situation where "you are correct" is my opinion now, and is likely to be for the foreseeable future, I would say:

> I think that you are correct

**live** can be a stative verb, for example it is when used to describe the place where you live:

> I live in Egypt

It can also be non-stative if you want to talk about a temporary situation:

> I am living in Egypt at the moment.

If we assume that these parallel universes have existed for ever and always will do, we can use the word **live** in a stative way.

> If this theory about parallel universes is correct, it means that we live in more than one universe at the same time.

Note that, as I have said, **live** can also be non-stative so the other version also makes sense, but might suggest that it's some kind of temporary arrangement.

Note also that a university is not the same thing as a universe :-)